# Does JDK automatically generate proxy classes for custom annotations?

Tags: java

Here is my code(JDK1.8):

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(value={ElementType.TYPE})
@Documented
public @interface MyAnnotation {
}
```

```
@MyAnnotation
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class<Main> cls = Main.class;
        Annotation[] annotations = cls.getDeclaredAnnotations();
        Arrays.stream(annotations).forEach(an -> {
            if (an instanceof MyAnnotation) {
                System.out.println("proxy");
            } else {
                System.out.println("???");
            }
            System.out.println(an.getClass().getName());
        });
    }
}
```

i test on windows,centos7 and ubuntu got the same result:

```
proxy
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1
```

My question: Is this my environment problem or JDK will automatically generate a proxy class? if it is the latter,why? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What was your expected result?

Comment: @Thilo `com.company.MyAnnotation`

Comment: @Shark: `MyAnnotation` is an interface. No object instance can ever return that for `.getClass()`. I think you want `an.getAnnotationType()`.

Comment: @Thilo Yes, this is exactly what I want to know. Thx a lot. It seems I got into a dead end just now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [9.6. Annotation Types:](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6)

> An annotation type declaration specifies a new annotation type, a special kind of interface type."

As interfaces cannot be instatiated directly, there has to be some kind of object implementing that interface that is returned from the reflection API methods. Whether that is a proxy or some other kind of anonymous class is up to the implementation.